# Port binding error while starting HL7 service in Siddhi SDK using IntelliJ IDEA plugin

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sdk, siddhi

I try to develop a Siddhi extension using the plugin for IntelliJ. When I try to configure a "hl7" source on any port the HL7Service seems to be started twice. This does not work since a network port can only be opened once.

I checked that no other Siddhi instance is running and I tried many different ports.

```
@App:name('HL7SiddhiApp')
@App:description('Description of the plan')
@source(type = 'hl7', port = "7777", hl7.encoding = "er7", @map(type = 'text'))
define stream hl7stream (message string);

@sink(type = 'log', @map(type = 'passThrough'))
define stream outStream (message string);

from hl7stream
select message
insert into outStream;
```

```
[ca.uhn.hl7v2.util.Home] : hapi.home is set to C:\Workspace\IdeaProjects\HelloSiddhi\HL7Siddhi\.
[ca.uhn.hl7v2.VersionLogger] : HAPI version is: 2.2
[ca.uhn.hl7v2.VersionLogger] : Default Structure libraries found for HL7 versions 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.5.1, 
[ca.uhn.hl7v2.conf.store.FileProfileStore] : Profile store directory doesn't exist: C:\Workspace\IdeaProjects\HelloSiddhi\HL7Siddhi\./profiles
[ca.uhn.hl7v2.concurrent.Service] : Starting service HL7 Server
[ca.uhn.hl7v2.app.HL7Service] : Starting ConnectionCleaner service
[ca.uhn.hl7v2.concurrent.Service] : Starting service ConnectionCleaner
[ca.uhn.hl7v2.app.SimpleServer] : Starting SimpleServer running on port 7777
[ca.uhn.hl7v2.concurrent.Service] : Thread ConnectionCleaner entering main loop
[ca.uhn.hl7v2.concurrent.Service] : Starting service Socket Acceptor
[ca.uhn.hl7v2.concurrent.Service] : Thread HL7 Server entering main loop
[ca.uhn.hl7v2.concurrent.Service] : Thread Socket Acceptor entering main loop
[ca.uhn.hl7v2.concurrent.Service] : Prepare to stop thread HL7 Server
INFO  [org.wso2.siddhi.sdk.launcher.LauncherUtils] - Event Input file is not provided or file is empty
[ca.uhn.hl7v2.concurrent.Service] : Starting service HL7 Server
[ca.uhn.hl7v2.app.HL7Service] : Starting ConnectionCleaner service
[ca.uhn.hl7v2.concurrent.Service] : Starting service ConnectionCleaner
[ca.uhn.hl7v2.app.SimpleServer] : Starting SimpleServer running on port 7777
[ca.uhn.hl7v2.concurrent.Service] : Starting service Socket Acceptor
[ca.uhn.hl7v2.concurrent.Service] : Thread HL7 Server entering main loop
[ca.uhn.hl7v2.concurrent.Service] : Thread ConnectionCleaner entering main loop
[ca.uhn.hl7v2.concurrent.Service] : Thread exiting main loop due to exception:
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at ca.uhn.hl7v2.app.AcceptorThread.afterStartup(AcceptorThread.java:106)
    at ca.uhn.hl7v2.concurrent.Service.run(Service.java:202)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following command to check which ports are in use on your local machine and which process is using it. Try a port that is not there in the output.

```
sudo netstat -tulpn
```

- t: tcp
- u: udp
- l: listening ports
- p: process n: network

Comment: Hi Chiran, thanks for the hint. Netstat says that port 7777 is available before starting the Siddhi SDK. After starting this port is successfully bound by the first instance of "ca.uhn.hl7v2.app.SimpleServer". I have to find out why a second instance is started on the same port and how to avoid it.

Comment: In the stacktrace you provided, we have two entries of the following.
[ca.uhn.hl7v2.app.SimpleServer] : Starting SimpleServer running on port 7777

In other words, it tries to start the server twice. As per the code in https://github.com/wso2-extensions/siddhi-io-hl7/blob/master/component/src/main/java/org/wso2/extension/siddhi/io/hl7/source/Hl7Source.java#L243 the hl7Service is not closed in a finally block, which might lead to bounded port even if the extension retries from Siddhi due to the ConnectionUnavailableException.

Comment: You can try your Siddhi app with the Stream Processor Editor(https://docs.wso2.com/display/SP440/Stream+Processor+Studio+Overview), so that we can verify that the hl7 behaves as expected.

Comment: Running the provided Siddhi app with the Stream Processor Editor works fine. The problem occurs only in the IntelliJ IDEA Siddhi SDK.